# Stash out of memory

Tags: bitbucket-server

I set the max-memory to 2 gigabytes in the setenv.bat file but it still runs out of memory at about 800MB of java allocated memory.

Is this normal?

Running on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Depends. Do you _have_ 2GB of free memory?

Comment: And this is probably off-topic. ServerFault might be a better home

Answer (score 1):

It's not normal. Stash is usually pretty good about memory. You might want to raise a support ticket at:

https://support.atlassian.com/

They'll probably ask you to create a heap dump so they can see what might be causes problems.